# Finding fitting distribution of a dataset

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have a dataset with information about the logistic delay supplying parts and components for a car manufacturer. The dataset contains 306 490 entries. My task task is the following:
How is the logistics delay distributed? Proof your selection by statistical tests and briefly describe your approach.

I have created a density histogramm and plotted a theoretical normal curve with the mean and standart deviation of the dataset and got this [Histogramm with theoretical normal distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyqxY.png).

The histogram is shifted towards the left therefore I created a QQ-Plot to further visualize and judge if it is a normal distribution: [QQ-Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXjyA.png). It doesn't quite fit but I'm not sure about rejecting a normal distribution yet therefore I performed a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test with the R programming language, used the ks.test() function and got following result:

```
## 
##  One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
## 
## data:  log_delay_tidy$Differenz
## D = 0.44182, p-value < 2.2e-16
## alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The p-value is much smaller than 0,05 so I rejected the null-hypothesis. I'm not quite sure if this test is suitable for a dataset of this dimention but my next thought was a log-normal distribution so I took the logarithm of the whole dataset and feeded it to the same KS-Test resulting in:

```
## 
##  One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
## 
## data:  logaritmiert
## D = 0.20665, p-value < 2.2e-16
## alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

This also results in rejection of the null-hypothesis. I don't know much about statistics therefore I don't know if this last result was predictable without performing it. I don't know what else to do from here. It seems like a normal distribution to me but the outliers may influence the test too much for it to deliver a proper result. What could be my next step?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why with so many observations that you need a parametric representation of the distribution?  Why not use a nonparametric density estimate? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)  Also, does the data consist of integers?  Or is the data more continuous?